# "Should I say "I asked 'TO NOT' / NOT advertise here"?

Tags: prepositions, negation

When I'm talking about the past, that I talked that I don't allow to advertise in my place,  which of the following forms are the right?

> 1) "I asked **TO NOT** advertise here"
>
> 2) "I asked **NOT** advertise here" (I asked not to do that)

3) something else

Comment: Just like you say in the parentheses: 3) "I asked NOT TO advertise here"

Comment: @VictorBazarov No; with *ask*, an infinitival without an express subject takes the subject of the head clause as its subject.

Comment: @StoneyB: so, in the parentheses ("I asked not to do that") is different because it has "that"?  Got any other examples?

Comment: @VictorBazarov "I asked not to do that" expands to something like "I asked that I be permitted to abstain from doing that". OP needs something with an express subject: "I asked them not to do that" or "I asked that they not do that" (but *do* in that last one will be parsed as a 'mandative subjunctive'). If there's no subject available, you have to rewrite: "I forbade/prohibited advertising in my place"

Comment: @StoneyB So, without rewriting, the OP needs "them" or "you" in the sentence, and then it would be "I asked ***you*** **not to** do that".  So, when the OP is talking to those to whom he previously forbade advertising in OP's place, would "you" **not** be **assumed**?

Comment: I guess not (upon further reading of your comments).

Comment: This question needs some clarification.  Are you trying to state that you prohibit advertising, or that you want to avoid advertising, or something else entirely?

Comment: I'm talking about prohibit and avoid advertising

Answer (score 1):

Close, the following would probably be the best way to phrase it.

You are asking a person not to do something:

> I asked you not to advertise here

Or alternately:

> I asked people not to advertise here
>
> I asked everyone to not advertise here

The last example wouldn't technically be wrong, but the former two flow better.

Comment: bingo. Asked usually needs a direct object or a preposition. Something has to fulfill the meaning, and an infinitive phrase doesn't satisfy on its own.